# Issue with prvtmail.plb in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

When I'm trying run below code in `Oracle 11g`,

```
@?/rdbms/admin/prvtmail.plb
```

I got this output.

```
PACKAGE utl_mail_internal compiled
PACKAGE BODY utl_mail_internal compiled
GRANT succeeded.
PACKAGE BODY utl_mail compiled
219/59         PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_TCP' must be declared
219/13         PL/SQL: Statement ignored
239/41         PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_TCP' must be declared
237/17         PL/SQL: Statement ignored
255/39         PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_TCP' must be declared
253/15         PL/SQL: Statement ignored
291/41         PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_TCP' must be declared
289/9          PL/SQL: Statement ignored
317/5          PLS-00201: identifier 'SYS.UTL_MAIL_INTERNAL' must be declared
317/5          PL/SQL: Statement ignored
389/23         PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_SMTP' must be declared
389/23         PL/SQL: Item ignored
390/39         PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_TCP' must be declared
390/23         PL/SQL: Item ignored
427/9          PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
427/9          PL/SQL: Statement ignored
443/19         PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
443/5          PL/SQL: Statement ignored
444/19         PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
444/5          PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

There are some errors in above output. How could I avoid those errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by executing the code as `sys`, not `system`.

Answer (score 0):

log in as sys and try this

GRANT EXECUTE ON UTL_TCP TO PUBLIC